# Apache server, Tomcat : Creating two instances of Tomcat with one in standby and managed by Apache.

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, standby

I am working on a Debian X64 server in which I have to perform a setup with Apache server and tomcat. What I am trying to do is to create two copies of Apache tomcat, with the 2nd one in `stand-by`.

In the event of a failure by the first Tomcat instance/copy, when it goes down automatically/error/manually, then the 2nd instance should be activated.

I am able to tie two instances of Apache tomcat on different ports, that is not the problem. But how to keep another Tomcat on stand-by and use it automatically in-case of failure, that part I am not able to figure out. 
This is what I have till now :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.domain_tomcat.com
ServerAlias domain_tomcat.com
ProxyRequests on
ProxyPreserveHost On
<Proxy *>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Proxy>
ErrorDocument 503 /maintenance.html
 ErrorDocument 404 /maintenance.html
 ErrorDocument 500 /maintenance.html

ProxyPass /maintenance.html !

ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/

<Location / >
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Location>
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.domain_tomcat.com
ServerAlias domain_tomcat.com
ProxyRequests on
ProxyPreserveHost On
<Proxy *>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Proxy>
ErrorDocument 503 /maintenance.html
 ErrorDocument 404 /maintenance.html
 ErrorDocument 500 /maintenance.html

ProxyPass /maintenance.html !

ProxyPass / http://localhost:8081/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8081/

<Location / >
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

First tomcat's server.xml :

```
 <Connector port="8080" proxyPort="80" redirectPort="443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" compression="force" compress$
               connectionTimeout="20000"  maxPostSize="5242880"
               URIEncoding="utf-8"
 compressableMimeType="text/html,text/xml,text/plain,text/css,text/ javascript,application/x-javascript,application/javascript"/>


 <Connector port="443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"  maxPostSize="5242880" SSLEnabled="true" maxThreads="200" compr$
              compressionMinSize="1024" scheme="https" secure="true" clientAuth="false"  sslProtocol="TLS"
               keystoreFile="keystore.jks" keystorePass="PASSWORD" URIEncoding="utf-8"
 compressableMimeType="text/html,text/xml,text/plain,text/css,text/ javascript,application/x-javascript,application/javascript"/>
```

Second tomcat's server.xml :

```
 <Connector port="8081" proxyPort="80" redirectPort="443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" compression="force" compress$
               connectionTimeout="20000"  maxPostSize="5242880"
               URIEncoding="utf-8"
 compressableMimeType="text/html,text/xml,text/plain,text/css,text/ javascript,application/x-javascript,application/javascript"/>


 <Connector port="443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"  maxPostSize="5242880" SSLEnabled="true" maxThreads="200" compr$
              compressionMinSize="1024" scheme="https" secure="true" clientAuth="false"  sslProtocol="TLS"
               keystoreFile="keystore.jks" keystorePass="PASSWORD" URIEncoding="utf-8"
 compressableMimeType="text/html,text/xml,text/plain,text/css,text/ javascript,application/x-javascript,application/javascript"/>
```

Now, how to bind all these together, and is this approach correct. Kindly let me know. Thank you.

Comment: Wouldn't you rather run each tomcat on a different server, with load balancing or failover? Alternatively, a script which somehow checks if tomcat is down and then restart it?

Comment: This [link](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy_balancer.html) might by helpful

Comment: @sbrattla : Because most of the time whenever tomcat dies, it happens because the JVM itself died(once in 1-2 months). We have other mechanisms to detect that the JVM died, but the service must keep running, that's why I need it on the same server.

Comment: @andrewdleach : Thanks for the comment, can you please elaborate more on how I can use that module. Thank you.

Comment: I'm not familiar with how Apache solves this, but you could alternatively use Varnish for the very same purpose. You could use it's fallback director to prioritize which servers (in your case same server, different ports) it should use first and second. https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/3.0/reference/vcl.html

Comment: @WeareBorg it helps potentially because it deals with the issue you describe of potentially disabled workers in a load balancing scheme. **_If some workers are disabled, the others will still be scheduled correctly._** --> Look for this line in the page

Comment: @andrewdleach : Thanks, I found that line, but it's just an explanation of a algorithm and the other balancers I see are configured based upon IP-address, so not very useful. Can you kindly specifically point out what is going to help for this problem or maybe write an answer. Thank you.